# Sending Private MOTD messages to Users from Server

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, hosting

I have recently started a small Team Fortress 2 dedicated Windows Server on my PC for just a few friends to join. However if it may start to get popular, how would I send I private message to a user saying:

```
Welcome to my server <their Steam name>
```

Could I do this through a command in a cfg file or would I need some sort of server mod to send private messages with variables in (like their Steam name)?

Please ask if you need any more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***What you are looking for is called Motd, which is [message of the day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)),  or [motto of the day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Motto_of_the_day).***

**Way 1)**

*No mods needed but it is doesn't work thru chat.*

I found a [Steam Guide by Jimo](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=143877817) about it. You basically create a png image, pick a background color, create an html for it (all available there), then you upload it to a website, save the URL to a txt file called motd.txt and then copy it to orangebox/tf.

This is how it'll look:
[image: motd by jimo]
Image courtesy [Jimo](http://jimo.co.uk/).

**Way 2)**

*Use a mod, which you can find from [here](http://sourcemod.net/plugins.php?mod=0&title=motd&search=1&sortby=mod&order=0).*

Comment: Do most people not have HTML MOTDs off?

Comment: Or just use Txt motd. Don't put link in txt, put the text.

Comment: Would it be possible to type the HTML directly into motd.txt?

Comment: AFAIK no, just get a github page (register to github, create a repository called thelinkyouwant.github.io, put html there, go to thelinkyouwant.github.io/thenameofthehtmlfile.html). Example: http://ardaozkal.github.io/richtest.html It is %100 free with 0 ads.